pdf rendering issue with barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
%PDF-1.7 1 0 obj << /Type /Catalog /Outlines 2 0 R /Pages 3 0 R >> endobj 2 0 obj << /Type /Outlines /Count 0 >> endobj 3 0 obj << /Type /Pages /Kids [6 0 R 11 0 R 13 0 R 15 0 R ] 
... 
../Producer (��dompdf 2.0.8 + CPDF) /CreationDate (D:20240717205606+05'30') /ModDate (D:20240717205606+05'30') /Title (�,�PCV Template) >> endobj 6 0 obj .c< /Type Wage /MediaBox [0.000 0.000 841.890 1190.550] /Parent 3 0 R /Contents 7 0 R>> endobj 7 0 obj << /Filter /FlateDecode /Length 7095 >> stream
x��e�■1�0r6) �W��L� 0 .i..6g$Y0 0 �0p8�,�0 ...             etc.

controller code
I have been trying to fix this error for 4-5 hours. Please take a look and tell me how to fix it.
$pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.cv',['candidates_data' => $candidate])->setPaper('A3','portrait');

return $pdf->stream('cv.pdf');`


As mentioned in comments, you can save your file using the download method instead of stream
return $pdf->download('cv.pdf');

Or you can tell your browser to show your stream as a PDF by setting a bunch of the following headers:
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');


It's working with IDM download manager, but without no result. It didn't show an error.
